# Storing (and using) file naming schemas to a class property

Tags: c#, serialization, properties

I have a project that contains a `stateProfile` class and an `Inquiry` class.
The `Inquiry` class is static and it's job is to create a text file. The text file's contents are calculated using information stored in the properties of a `stateProfile` object (one for each State in the USA, that winds up being read in from an XML file).

I had been able to share a global naming schema for all of the states but I now have requirements to meet for naming them based on the `stateProfile` object.

For example:
I have a `stateProfile` for Kansas and another for Missouri.

```
Inquiry inquiry = new Inquiry();
foreach(stateProfile p in _listOfProfiles){
     inquiry.CreateFile(p);
}
```

in `Inquiry.CreateFile(stateProfile p)` I have the expression that defines the filename:

```
sOutFileName = $"{p.prop1}_{p.prop2}_Literal3_{_staticProp.ToString("D4")}.txt";
```

Any suggestions for being able to store the logic/expression in a property like `stateProfile.outFileName` such as

```
public string outFileName {
     $"{p.prop1}_{p.prop2}_Literal3_{_staticProp.ToString("D4")}.txt";
}
```

and then be able to refer to that property in `Inquiry.CreateFile(stateProfile p)` like the following?

```
sOutFileName = $"{p.outFileName}";
```

Comment: If you change p to this in outFileName, make it a method and pass in _staticProp as an argument would that not work?

Comment: Making `outFileName` a method of `stateProfile` (as opposed to a property) unfortunately doesn't give me the flexibility I'm looking for. If the naming for a state becomes something completely different such as p.prop1 and p.prop2 switching places.

Comment: Adding a little bit of clarifying information: A List<stateProfile> is serialized to an XML file on program closing. This XML is read back in on the program load. The text file that is ultimately output by `Inquiry` is written using information from the current `stateProfile` object. Looking to store the naming logic to each stateProfile and most of the variables that will make up name will also come that object from other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this some more, [Alex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559114/storing-and-using-file-naming-schemas-to-a-class-property#comment114154667_64559114) was the way to go.

Since all of the properties I am looking to use in constructing the filename formulas are belonging to the `stateProfile` object, I make a method `GetFileName()` class member and pass in anything else I might need.

I use a switch statement, which could get unwieldy as the number of states I have to consider grows, but for now it works.

```
        public string GetFileName(int prop1) {
            string sOutFileName = "";
            switch (SourceState) {
                case "MO":
                    sOutFileName = $"ReqPref_{this.stProfPropA}_{prop1}.txt";
                    break;
                default:
                    sOutFileName = $"{this.stProfPropB}_{prop1}.txt";
                    break;
            }
            return sOutFileName;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this sort of approach might be what you are looking for. It allows you to embed C# scripts into your XML and interpret them in code.

Every State could have a different filename format now.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This was read from your XML file.
            var filenameFormatterScript = "p => $\"{p.Name.ToLower()}.txt\"";

            var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(StateProfile).Assembly);
        
            var sp = new StateProfile
            {
                Name = "Alabama",
                FilenameFormatter = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<StateProfile, string>>(filenameFormatterScript, options)
            };

            Console.WriteLine(sp.Filename());

        }
    }

    public class StateProfile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Func<StateProfile, string> FilenameFormatter { get; set; }

        public string Filename()
        {
            return FilenameFormatter(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'm trying to refactor this around one more prerequisite and having a little bit of trouble. The XML file is actually the serialized result of a `StateProfile` object. On program exit I write to this XML and on load I read from it. I would like to move the string you have with delegate in it (fileFormatterScript) to be another property of `StateProfile`.